# getActivity() returning null

Tags: android

I am trying to connect to the network using getActivity(). My code is given below:

```
public void calledHandler(View view){
    //Return a handle to the system-level service by name
    if(getActivity()==null){
        Log.d("Yes", "IT IS NULL");
    }
    ConnectivityManager connmngr=(ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo networkinfo=connmngr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkinfo!=null && networkinfo.isConnected()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), new DownloadWebpageTask().doInBackground(stringurl), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        textview.setText(new DownloadWebpageTask().doInBackground(stringurl));
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No network connection available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        textview.setText("No network connection available");
    }   
}
```

getActivity() keeps returning null. Is there a possible solution to the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: No, I didn't use it. Does it help?

Comment: Are you working with fragments or just activities? In that case use getApplicationContext() as shayan provided.

Comment: I keep getting a NullPointerException at the ConnectivityManager line. To debug, I added that Log.d message and it shows getActivity() to be returning null every time.

Comment: try to get `Activity` reference `onAttach(....)`

Comment: I am working with fragments.

Comment: @user2994590 The best to get rid of this is to keep activity reference when `onAttach(.........)` is called and use the activity reference wherever needed

Comment: You really don't need getActivity() to use those methods. You can use Context instead. But you should show the code where you are calling that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use onAttach like so:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

// Examples of how to use getActivity()
    db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    androidId = Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
}
```

This is copied from one of my projects that uses fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Activity is not always available in a Fragment.
You can call `getActivity()` after `onAttach()` is called but before `onDetach()` is called.

You can use `getActivity()` during most of the callback methods like `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()` etc, but **never** in constructor.

You should stop all threads and cancel all handler callbacks in `onPause()` or `onStop()` of the Fragment.